# mongoose schema with array returned null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have my data like this in my database

```
[{
  "birth-date": "18/12/2010",
  "babies": [{
    "name": "James",
    "age": 8,
  }, {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 4,
  }]
}]
```

So I do my schema like below

```
var babiesSchema = new Schema({
    birth-date: Date, // tried String too
    babies: [{
        name: String,
        age: Number
    }]
});

var Babies = mongoose.model('babies', babiesSchema);
```

I do

```
Babies.find({}, function(response){
    res.json(response)
  })
```

I got `null`, is something wrong with my schema? There is no error in my node's terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that nothing is wrong with your schema. You just need to read documentation more carefully.

If you look [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) you will find that callback should have 2 parameters. First is for error and second is for result of search. So `null` means that there is no error. I would try to change code like this:

```
Babies.find({}, function(err, foundBabies){
    res.json(foundBabies)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Babies.find({}).exec(function (err, babies) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Cannot find Babies'
            });
        } else {
            res.json(babies);
        }
    });
```